# For Each loop on filtered data returning 0 results, no errors

Tags: excel, vba, foreach, visible

I need to generate a sheet of values out of a database between dates that the user selects. The date is in column 2 of the database, but I need the whole row for every date in this range. I got some advice to use a For Each instead to more easily use the `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`. While I am no longer getting any errors I also get no data in my product worksheet. Could someone tell me why I am not returning data?

```
Sub Generate()

Dim g As Integer
Dim h As Integer
Dim datemin As String
Dim datemax As String

datemin = CDbl(CDate(Sheets("start").Cells(15, 8)))
datemax = CDbl(CDate(Sheets("start").Cells(15, 9)))


Worksheets("Database").Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=">=" & datemin, _
        Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & datemax


g = 0

For Each Row In Worksheets("database").Range("A1")
    g = g + 1
    If Cells(g, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) = True And Cells(g, 1) <> "" Then

Sheets("product").Activate
Dim NextRow As Long
NextRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 10

'fill KPI
Cells(NextRow, 1) = Format(Sheets("database").Cells(g, 1), "mm/dd/yyyy")  'Date1
Cells(NextRow, 2) = Format(Sheets("database").Cells(g, 2), "mm/dd/yyyy")  'Date2
Cells(NextRow, 3) = Sheets("database").Cells(g, 3)  'value1
Cells(NextRow, 4) = Sheets("database").Cells(g, 4)  'value2
Cells(NextRow, 6) = Sheets("database").Cells(g, 5)  'value3
Cells(NextRow, 9) = Sheets("database").Cells(g, 8)  'comment
Cells(NextRow, 13) = Sheets("database").Cells(g, 6)  'person
    Else
        Exit For
    End If

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: `Sheets("Database").Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` returns a range and it is expecting a Boolean.

Comment: Sorry I'm pretty new to VBA, how would I fix this/get around that mismatch?

Comment: If you are trying to copy filtered cells, why not just copy them in one go and dispense with the loop?

Comment: My thought is to loop because each database record has one date attached, and the sheet that is being created can be any length of time determined by the end user. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only 'looping' through one cell - A1.

If you want to use a loop for this try looping through all the rows on the database and checking if they are visible or not.

If they are visible then copy the relevant data to the other sheet.

```
Sub Generate()
Dim rngDst As Range
Dim rngSrc As Range
Dim datemin As String
Dim datemax As String
Dim g As Integer
Dim h As Integer

    datemin = CDbl(CDate(Sheets("start").Cells(15, 8)))
    datemax = CDbl(CDate(Sheets("start").Cells(15, 9)))


    Worksheets("Database").Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=">=" & datemin, _
                                                      Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & datemax

    Set rngSrc = Worksheets("Database").Range("A2")
    Set rngDst = Worksheets("Product").Range("A11")
    
    Do
    
        
        If Not rngSrc.EntireRow.Hidden And rngSrc.Value <> "" Then

            'fill KPI
            rngDst.Value = Format(rngSrc.Value, "mm/dd/yyyy")  'Date1
            rngDst.Offset(, 1).Value = Format(rngSrc.Offset(, 1).Value, "mm/dd/yyyy") 'Date2
            rngDst.Offset(, 2).Value = rngSrc.Offset(, 2).Value 'value1
            rngDst.Offset(, 3).Value = rngSrc.Offset(, 3).Value 'value2
            rngDst.Offset(, 5).Value = rngSrc.Offset(, 4).Value 'value3
            rngDst.Offset(, 8).Value = rngSrc.Offset(, 7).Value 'comment
            rngDst.Offset(, 12).Value = rngSrc.Offset(, 5).Value 'person
            Set rngDst = rngDst.Offset(1, 0)
        End If
        
        Set rngSrc = rngSrc.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop Until rngSrc = ""

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! When I run this I am now getting a run time error '1004' application defined or object defined error at the "Set ranDest" line. Any idea where this comes from? It may be worth mentioning that the source sheet has 1 row of headers, and the destination sheet has 10 rows of headers.

Comment: If I change the rngDst line to Set rngDst = Sheets("IDS_RFPC_02").Range("A11") then the error goes away, but I only get one row of data. Is it still not looping correctly? I have double checked to make sure I have made every change you made in your code above.